# Interacting with local Google API's using dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build a service in Google App/Compute Engine that sends bulk push notifications to [Apples Push notification service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

Unfortunately I am hitting limitations with appengine, and the use of sockets, so have moved over to:

- A managed vm **(call this Service A)**
- An appengine app, with a pull task queue **(call this Service B)**.

My question is, is it possible to run Service A locally with `dev_appserver.py` and use a client library, e.g [google-api-python](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) within Service B, to pull tasks from Service A ? e.g:

`from apiclient.discovery import build`

`service = build('taskqueue','v1beta2', api_url='http://localhost:8080')`

Where localhost:8080 is the url to the dev_appserver instance of Service A

Notes:

- I'm not interested in a solution using [Googles Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)
- As an aside I'm happy to hear any pointers on making a scalable APNS service on appengine